# servlet not available error in eclipse spring mvc projects

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

i am running the project using eclipse. in one project i get the following error

> 18/02/2011 12:23:41 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
>   init INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat
>   Native library which allows optimal
>   performance in production environments
>   was not found on the
>   java.library.path:
>   C:\java\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\java\bin;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IDM Computer
>   Solutions\UltraEdit\;C:\java\bin
>   18/02/2011 12:23:42 AM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule
>   begin WARNING:
>   [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context}
>   Setting property 'source' to
>   'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:test' did
>   not find a matching property.
>   18/02/2011 12:23:42 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler
>   init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8085"]
>   18/02/2011 12:23:42 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler
>   init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
>   18/02/2011 12:23:42 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
>   load INFO: Initialization processed in
>   511 ms 18/02/2011 12:23:42 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService
>   startInternal INFO: Starting service
>   Catalina 18/02/2011 12:23:42 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine
>   startInternal INFO: Starting Servlet
>   Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.8 18/02/2011
>   12:23:42 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log INFO: Marking servlet ds as
>   unavailable 18/02/2011 12:23:42 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   loadOnStartup SEVERE: Servlet /test
>   threw load() exception
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1048)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:996)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4834)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5155)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5150)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   18/02/2011 12:23:42 AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler
>   start INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-bio-8085"] 18/02/2011 12:23:42
>   AM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler
>   start INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-bio-8009"] 18/02/2011 12:23:42
>   AM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
>   start INFO: Server startup in 332 ms
>   18/02/2011 12:23:52 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke INFO: Servlet ds is currently
>   unavailable

my ds.servlet is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.orf/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <!-- Configuring DataSource -->
    <bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springdb</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>root</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>root</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!-- Configuring jdbcTemplate -->
    <bean id="jdbctemp" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref local="datasource" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="loginModel" class="com.santosh.spring.LoginModel">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref local="jdbctemp" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="logincnt" class="com.santosh.spring.LoginController">
        <property name="loginModel" >
            <ref local="loginModel"/>
        </property>

        <!-- Configure Command ClassName  -->

        <property name="commandClass" >
        <value type="java.lang.Class"> com.santosh.spring.UserDetails </value>
        </property>

        <!-- Configure the command name , the name to use when binding the instantiated command class to the request -->

        <property name="commandName">
            <value> UserDetails </value>
        </property>

    </bean>


    <!-- Configure URL Mapping   -->

    <bean id="myurlmapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping" >
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="/login.spring">logincnt</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="urlMap">
<map>
<entry key="/hello.springs">
<ref bean="helloController"/>
</entry>
</map>
</property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="helloController" class="net.roseindia.web.HelloWorldController"> </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave is right. However, Tomcat has some hot-deployment issues because of which it sometimes fails to load the class which is actually present in the classpath. So, if you find that you actually have the jar at the right place, then simply clean the tomcat (right click the server and select clean) and then start again.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace is complaining that it can't find "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet". DispatcherServlet class can be found inside spring-webmvc.jar ([jarfinder.com](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet) is a good tool for figuring out which jars contain which classes), so double check that you have all the appropriate spring jars, like spring-core-x.jar, spring-webmvc-x.jar, etc on your class path in Eclipse (or perhaps under WEB-INF/lib, depending on how you're trying to run the webapp). [Maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework) is a good place to find the spring jars if you need them.

Comment: I have all the jars present , because if i run the other project it works fine , only this project has the problem

Comment: Is the build path for both the projects identical? Also, when you do "Run As..." in Eclipse, it automatically creates a Run Configuration. You might want to check that the 2 run configurations for both projects both have the same jars on the classpath.

Comment: yes both have same jars , i think problem is with the servlet config file